# payara / glassfish postgresql datasource jdbc connection pool

Tags: postgresql, glassfish, datasource, connection-pooling, payara

I'm setting up the JDBC connection pool for Java EE, Payara - PostgreSQL application.

Right now, I'm experiencing some unexpected slow SQL queries that happen randomly. Sometimes the SQL response for a simple select by PK can take more than 30 seconds.

I'm using org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource datasource, which does not perform connection pooling. This is the reason why i'm suspecting slow SQL sometimes.

I saw, that org.postgresql.ds.common.BaseDataSource has PGConnectionPoolDataSource, PGPoolingDataSource, PGSimpleDataSource, PGXADataSource implementations.

My questions is what it would be the best approach of choosing and tuning the best connection pool datasource implementation?

Maybe there are some other generic JDBC connection pool?

I've tried PGConnectionPoolDataSource which seems to have better performance.

The configured META-INF/glassfish-resources.xml looks like:

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"
                          name="PostgresPool"
                          res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
                          max-pool-size="100"
                          steady-pool-size="10"
                          is-connection-validation-required="true"
                          connection-validation-method="table"
                          validation-table-name="locale"
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="60">

        <property name="ServerName" value="localhost"></property>
        <property name="PortNumber" value="5432"></property>
        <property name="DatabaseName" value="my_db"></property>
        <property name="User" value="db_user"></property>
        <property name="Password" value="super_secret"></property>
        <property name="TcpKeepAlive" value="true"></property>
        <property name="Ssl" value="false"></property>
        <property name="Sslfactory" value="org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
```

Comment: How do you measure query performance? Did you got the number of established connections at that time? A pool will always help but might not be enough if slowness is caused by some other reason,

Comment: I'm using in persistence.xml, <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="com.acme.ltd.JPAEclipseLinkSessionCustomizer" /> which is eclipselink org.eclipse.persistence.config.SessionCustomizer. 
In this way, I added a custom AbstractSessionLog implementation that hook connections events and log time difference between RELEASE_CONNECTION and  
 ACQUIRE_CONNECTION.

Comment: Which payara version do you use? Is this a webapplication?

Comment: I'm using payara 4.1.2.181, but I have plan to upgrade to payara 5, for a java ee webapp